# Error No. 2003. Can't connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, database-connection, sqlyog

I has had two days searching and exploring solutions regarding the error 2003. 
Can't connect to mysql server on 'Server name'.

The firewall is off and I had added the port 3306, the one that mysql uses.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 5):

Please refer this FAQ which describes how to solve this issue: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Error No. 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (or some other host)

simply means that connection is not possible for one of the following (or similar) reasons:

- There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
- Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart the MySQL server for the change to take effect. SQLyog needs to connect using TCP-IP.
- Some networking issue prevents connection. It could be a network malconfiguration or a firewall issue.
- When trying to connect to a MySQL server at an ISP this error message often indicates that direct connection to MySQL has been blocked. You must then use HTTP-tunneling or SSH-tunneling to connect.

Comment: "Simply means", then lists four different, complex answers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.controll pannel->administrative tools->services->mysql and start mysql.Some times simple solution saves lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

normally means that there is no MySQL server running on the system .
check your server running

Answer (score 0):

this could be due to firewalls of the system try below command and check

service iptables stop

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue but i fix it.
my hostname is DEBIAN, i just modify the file my.cnf ( for mysql) and set bindaddress : 0.0.0.0

this option say to mysql to listen all interfaces. restart your server and finish

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Sever might not be installed.
Please refer this to install:
[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

Answer (score 0):

if your question refer to can't connect to mysql on hosting (cpanel), i also had same problem. 
I also turn off firewall, but it doesn't solve my problem. 
Rather than using server name or domain name on Mysql Host Address, i using ip address given by hosting provider.
And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Going to services and starting MYSQL service doesn't work for me.
Finally, I hit the following commands inside the MYSQL command-line client:
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance that you are making one of the two mistakes.
First :
You are inputting the wrong password. check your password  or change it with
this command
ALTER USER `'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'very_strong_password';`
In place of `'very_strong_password'` give a strong password of your choice.
Second:
You are using '@' in the password which can be confused with the other with @localhost.

Comment: Please fix formatting and spelling (you can use Grammarly or some service like this).

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me
Go to services and start MySql services
window: press the start button and search **services**. Then star MySql services
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case main application installer will install mysql and try to connect with odbc.  In that time it throws above error.  The password given for configuring mysql was wrong.  So I changed it.

Login as user root with blank password in mysql client.

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc';
```

Password changed and same password I used for configuration.